# How to free a double pointer?

Tags: c

In this function, I'm trying to delete a record and deallocate memory using free(), but somehow neither free(firstname[i]) or free(score[i]) does work. Please help!

```
void deRecords(char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score, int num)//function to delete records
{
    char *find;
    find=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));//allocating array to delete a record
    printf("*Delete Records*\n");
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s",find);

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(lastname[i],find)==0)//if match is found, replace array with null
        {
            firstname[i]=NULL;
            lastname[i]=NULL;
            score[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] is needed.

Comment: You don't just replace with null, `free()` first.

Comment: This would make a lot more sense if you had a simple `struct` with `first`, `last` and `score` properties.

Comment: There's no need to use `malloc()` for `find`, just declare `char find[10]`

Comment: If you `malloc` don't forget to `free` or this thing will leak memory really fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should free the name strings before setting them to `NULL`.

Also, before calling `strcmp()`, make sure that the entry isn't `NULL`, which would happen if that entry had previously been deleted.

```
void deRecords(char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score, int num)//function to delete records
{
    char find[100];
    printf("*Delete Records*\n");
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s",find);

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        if(lastname[i] && strcmp(lastname[i],find)==0)//if match is found, replace array with null
        {
            free(firstname[i]);
            firstname[i]=NULL;
            free(lastname[i]);
            lastname[i]=NULL;
            score[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And also to free a float, I tried free(score) and it also deletes memory of the next score, why is this so?

Comment: You don't need to `free(score)`. That's an array of floats, not an array of pointers to floats.